# Is there any other option to use instead of replace function for the given scenario

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having a column contains names with acronyms. Such as GDN,BLDG,MNS, etc. I have to change it to Garden, Building, Mansion etc.
I wrote the code below to do so

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  bld_name, 
  'GDNS', 'Gardens'), 
  'HSE', 'House'), 
  'HTS', 'Heights'),
  'CTR','Centre'),
  'BLDG','Building'),
  'MANS','Mansion'),
  'GDN', 'Garden'),
  'BLD','Building')  bld_name
```

Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: It would help to know what "sometimes it's not working" *means*. What are you seeing that makes you believe it's not working? Sample data and expected results would immensely improve this question.

Comment: Why not put the acronyms and names into a table and then join to it in your SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp function bulk_replace(text string) as (array(
  with dict as (
    select 'GDN' as part, 'Garden' replacement union all
    select 'BLDG', 'Building' union all
    select 'MNS', 'Mansion'
  )
  select string_agg(ifnull(replacement, part), '' order by offset)
  from unnest(regexp_extract_all(text, r'\b\w+\b|[^\w]+')) part with offset
  left join dict 
  using(part)
));
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 'GDN, some text BLDG, MNS more text' bld_name
)
select bulk_replace(bld_name) as bld_name
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

As an option - you can do the same but without using udf as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with dict as (
  select 'GDN' as part, 'Garden' replacement union all
  select 'BLDG', 'Building' union all
  select 'MNS', 'Mansion'
)
select (
    select string_agg(ifnull(replacement, part), '' order by offset)
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(bld_name, r'\b\w+\b|[^\w]+')) part with offset
    left join dict 
    using(part)
  ) as bld_name
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail 
Is it possible changing all the replace function with regex?